# Appliances in between studs shelving

Tags: kitchens, shelving

As part of my kitchen remodel, I am planning to install cabinets between studs.

Essentially these are about 14" x 3.5" shelves and can be installed between studs.

( if you google "between stud shelving", it will give you an idea of what I am talking about ).

Now - I am planning to widen one of the wall by installing three rows of studs so that the thickness of wall becomes 10.5" ( 3 * 3.5 ). This the shelves can be upto 10.5 inches wide ( enough to store toaster or toaster oven ).

There will be electrical wiring through studs and also issue of placing a toaster oven in recessed shelf in a wall.

My question is how to make all this setup according to code ?

Answer (score 2):

This won't go against any codes as long as you use the standard methods for wiring. The wires usually go through the studs via holes drilled through each board.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Comment: The toaster oven and toaster will generate heat. Won't I need some kind of heat resistant shelving ?

Comment: How much space do you have from the top of the toaster to the next shelf or ceiling?

Answer (score 2):

Any use outside of what is permitted in the appliance's operating manual is a code violation. Appliances that get hot will generally list required clearance space and limitations on supporting/surrounding surfaces.

The manual for mine says you must maintain 6" of clear space "from the wall and on all sides" (this would mean that it could not be used on the shelves you describe). It also says not to "set it on a finished wood table".

You also need to look into code firewall requirements for kitchen walls in your area, it may be that you have to line the alcove with drywall or somehow maintain fire rating of the walls another way.

[image]